# Implementing IBM Appcenter Rating Feature in another WL APP

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to implement IBM Appcenter rating feature in my worklight application. I was looking at the database table where the feedback gets stored. The table has a column named ID, and I am not able to understand that how the value for column ID is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for the source of application center...? When downloading it, you also got a MobileFirst project for the iOS application. There you have the source of the rating.

In the app the user clicks on a star icon in the AppCenter Installer app and this data is sent to the appcenter server and displayed in its management console, as well as in the Installer app itself.

Comment: You are right. What I'm trying to ask is that, when the app send the rating data to the database, it generates an ID for that record to be stored in the DB. What is the logic for generating the ID because ID is not given by the user.

Answer (score 0):

After pursuing IBM, they confirmed that this feature was removed after Worklight 6.1 version.